# jQuery array of integer (year) creates undefined rows

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a JSON source filled with database data I just want to reorganize.
First data has to be the "Year" (2018, 2019, 2020...) that will contains subdata.

Thus, I've build a new data array sourcing json data (in the example "source").

But when I finally log the new array (_data), I get an array with almost fully empty data...

... like :

```
Array(2020) [ undefined, undefined, undefined...]
```

Looking into it, I can see year 2018 and 2019 (the real data) correctly filled, with all others year 0 (!) to 2017 fully empty.

Why _data shows so much unused and helpless data ?

Here is the code

```
var hierarchicalData = function() {
    var _data = [];
    this.setup = function(source) {
        $.each(source, function(index, value) {
            var year = value.YEAR;
            if (typeof(_data[year]) === 'undefined') {
                console.log("Create year " + year);
                _data[year] = [];
            }
            // [... full other code generating subdata depending on year ...]
            var xxx = value.XXX;
            if (typeof(_data[year][xxx]) === 'undefined') {
                console.log("  Creation xxx (" + year + ', ' + xxx + ")");
                _data[year][xxx] = [];
            // ... and few others subdata
        }

        });
        console.log(_data);
    }
}
```

[Edit Start]
Call of function

```
newData = new hierarchicalData();
newData.setup(fullData.Extraction());
```

where

```
fullData.Extraction()
```

is original json data.

[Edit End]

Thanks.

Comment: That's what you would get if you did something like `var _data = Array(2020);`. I don't see anything like that in your code, so I suspect you didn't post the actual code.

Comment: _data is set as [] on 2nd line of what I've posted. This is my actual code. I just change "french words" to english et suppress subdata array generation...
I just can add call of setup :
    newData = new hierarchicalData();
    newData.setup(fullData.Extraction());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how javascript arrays work, the index of a value is determined by how many values come before it. So, if you declare a value like `arr[2018] = 'something'` it will add 2018 empty values before it. Use an object instead, this will store as key:value pairs with no need to add empty values.

```js
let arr = [];
arr[2018] = 'something';
console.log('arr.length:', arr.length)

let obj = {};
obj[2018] = 'something';
console.log('entire obj:', obj)
console.log('number of obj keys:', Object.keys(obj).length)
```

Comment: I've edited my purpose to add part of code with subdata... If I initiate arr[2018] with 'something', I'll get an error : _data[year][xxx] is undefined...

Comment: @BartmanDilaw He's just using that to demonstrate how sparse arrays work, it's not intended for you to use in your code.

Comment: @Barmar So it's not a solution, ok, got it.

Comment: The solution is the same as my suggestion: Use an object instead of an array.

Comment: Yes use objects instead of arrays `_data ={} ... _data[year] = {} ... _data[year][xxx] = {}` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since the array indexes you're using start around 2018, as soon as you assign `_data[2018]`, it will create an array that has `2019` elements, and all the elements from `0` to `2017` will be unassigned. This is because array indexes always start at `0`, so it needs something in all those earlier indexes.

This is called a "sparse array". Those unassigned elements don't actually take up memory, but when you view the array they'll be listed as undefined.

In Chrome, the console will abbreviate it:

```
(2019) [empty x 2018, [some data]]
```

If you don't want to see all these unused entries, use an object instead of an array for `_data`:

```
var _data = {};
```

Comment: That edit has been added to explain why Arleigh-Hix's solution will not work in my case

Comment: I don't see how the edit explains that. Your code uses `[]` as the `something` value.

Comment: My solution was use objects (`{}`) instead of arrays (`[]`)

Comment: @ArleighHix So does mine.

Comment: @Barmar I know, your answer is basically identical to mine